# Why does this work with Wolfram|Alpha but not Mathematica?

Tags: equation-solving, wolfram-alpha-queries

I ran into this while doing some work today:

[image]

It's the exact same syntax - and I expected that Mathematica would be more likely to be able to solve it, since oftentimes Wolfram|Alpha doesn't have all the functions of Wolfram Language. So why did this happen, and how can I make Mathematica solve it when, say, I'm offline and don't have access to Wolfram|Alpha queries?

I'm running Mathematica 10 on CentOS 6.

Comment: Feel free to come up with a more descriptive title..

Comment: W|A is assuming a space between h and w, whereas *Mathematica* does not.

Comment: Mathematica syntax is not correct. You need to put space (or *) between h and w.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wolfram|Alpha is more willing to change the input because the input is generally natural language. Alpha has interpreted `hw` has two single-letter symbols, `h` and `w`. Mathematica has interpreted `hw` as a single two-letter symbol. Because you asked Mathematica to solve for `h` and `h` does not appear in the expression, there is no solution. Adding a space tells Mathematica there are two symbols there and makes the thing work:

[image]